# django queryset count(*) over()

Tags: django, count, django-queryset

What would be corresponding django queryset function for `count(*) over()` in sql where you get count of total records for the query along with individual rows

```
select *,count(*) over() from users offset 2 limit 2
```

I am using

```
queryset.values()[offset:limit]
```

How to modify it to serve mentioned purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do *over* clause by using [Window expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) 
in your situation, it can be used like this:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Window
from django.db.models import Count

queryset.annotate(total_records=Window(Count('pk')))
```

for using slicing as offset and limit, it should be like `[offset:offset+limit]`

Comment: extra might also work similarly.